# Retrieving venmo payment information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, venmo

I'm currently using a link that looks something like this

```
<%= link_to "CLICK HERE TO PAY WITH VENMO", "https://venmo.com/?txn=pay&recipients=#{@post.venmo_name}&amount=#{@post.price}" %>
```

However I would like a way to verify that the user made the payment. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: I don’t think this is supported any more :(

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I work at Venmo.</sub>

You could use a [webhook](https://developer.venmo.com/docs/webhooks).

However, how are you confirming that the user who clicked on the link is the one who made the payment? (say two users click the link and only one makes a payment, how would you know which one made the payment?) Have you looked into using the [Oauth API](https://developer.venmo.com/docs/quickstart)?

Comment: I can check information from the webhook against their account. My problem is that I do not know how to get a webhook.

Comment: Have you looked at the webhook documentation? https://developer.venmo.com/docs/webhooks

Comment: How do i know if my venmo app webhook has been verified? And do I have to always keep the verification on my webhook page? Or do I just need it originally to verify the page once? Here is my PHP code to verify... is that all I need to verify? <?php
    #Venmo ipn webhook verification
    echo $_GET['venmo_challenge'];
    exit;
?>